# the contents of my website is not showing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, react-three-fiber

When I deployed my react website with three fiber, the contents such as my html would show at first  before the content in the div start disappearing on the live. The js would load at first and then disappear. The model did not show at all.

Here is the live site:
https://xavi4075.github.io/portfolio/

It was fine before I compiled and exported onto github. I have no idea why this is happening

the development build is currently facing the same issues as the live one .The hosted code is on the gh-pages branch. The only thing that seems to be working is the background.

I did this from gui's response

[image: I did this from gui's response]

however this was the response from the live site.  It is working now in the development site with the fetch being portfolio/assets/airplane.fbx. how can I get rid of the second portfolio?

[image: however this was the response from the live site. It is working now in the development site with the fetch being portfolio/assets/airplane.fbx. how can I get rid of the second portfolio]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only actionable item I can discern is your model not showing up. This is because the fetch for it is returning a 404 error. I'm unsure if this is the cause of everything else not loading correctly but if you open your console you'll see something like this:
[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOfcP.png)

I believe if you change the fetch from `https://xavi4075.github.io/assets/airplane.fbx` to  `https://xavi4075.github.io/portfolio/assets/airplane.fbx`. Your model should show up since that is where your model lives in your files.

Comment: I changed it but it's not working

Comment: The fetch is displaying as portfolio/portfolio/assets/airplane.fbx. however, it is working in the development version showing as portfolio/assets/airplane.fbx